# Minimization of sphere in 3D with two linear constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning

I am trying to solve the minimization problem below.
In the first case with only one constraint, the optimal point is easily reached to be $x* = (1,1,1)$ with Lagrange's multiplier value $λ=-1$.
But, in the second case with one additional constraint, the new constraint is more extended than the first one and consequently I get the answer $x* = (6/7,12/7,17/7)$. Thus, the optimal point is again $x* = (1,1,1)$ which comes from a tighter constraint, isn't it?

[image]
*Black plane: $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 3$

**Blue Plane: $x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 3x_{3} = 12$

Then, why the problem statement mentions that "the second minimum value should be less than the first minimum value"??

In other words, how the second constraint $x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 3x_{3} = 12$ really affect the previous optimal point reached by applying the first constraint $x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 3$?

***Find the minimum value of $F(x) = 1/2 (x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3})$ with one constraint
$x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} = 3$ and then with an additional constraint $x_{1} + 2x_{2} + 3x_{3} = 12$.
The second minimum value should be less than the first minimum value : Why ?
The first problem has a ??? tangent to a sphere in R3 .
The second problem has a ??? tangent to a sphere in R3 .***

Comment: how is the optimization problem linked to a sphere? where does the question come from?

Comment: "Linear Algebra and Learning from Data" by "Gilbert Strang". Chapter VI.II, Exercise 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that if the restrictions separated are

$$
\cases{
R_1\to x_1+x_2+x_3 = 3\\
R_2\to x_1+2x_2+3x_3 = 12}
$$

the minimization is with $R = R_1\cap R_2$ or the restriction $R$ defines a line while each of the restrictions $R_1,R_2$ define planes. Obviously $R\in R_1$ and $R\in R_2$ so consequently

$$
\min_{x\in R} F(x) \ge \min_{x\in R_1} F(x)
$$

or

$$
\min_{x\in R} F(x) \ge \min_{x\in R_2} F(x)
$$

Here we assumed $F(x) = \frac 12(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)$

NOTE

In the last case, the lagramgian reads

$$
L(x,\lambda) = F(x) + \lambda_1 R_1 +\lambda_2 R_2
$$

and the stationary points are given by the solutions to

$$
\nabla L = \cases{x_1+\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 = 0\\ x_2 +\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 = 0 \\ x_3 + \lambda_1+3\lambda_3 = 0\\ x_1+x_2+x_3 = 3 \\ x_1+2x_2+3x_3 = 12}
$$

giving only one stationary point which is $x^* = (-2,1,4)$ with $F(x^*) = 10.5$

Comment: I understand your logic, But I do not think it is correct here. Because, If you draw both planes and consider the line of intersection between two restrictions $R = R_{1} ∩ R_{2}$, you will see that this line is far more extended and away rather than the first plane of $R_{1}$! Then, it cannot lead to second min value less than the first one!

Comment: Sorry. I had changed the values on the relationships above. Now is corrected.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried your advice/method and as you said I got a line constraint from $R=R1∩R2 $. However. the minimum point on that line is $x*=(-2,+1,+4)$. putting this point in $F(x_{i})$ gives $F_{min} = 21/2$ which is still larger than $F_{min} = 3/2$ resulted from only first constraint...

Comment: I think maybe the writer's mean from "Less" was actually not the norm of $x∗$ but the value of the solution regarding its sign! In this case, since the second case with two constraints has a minus sign $x_{1}=-2$ then your answer should be correct